# In Vim, why doesn't my mouse work past the 220th column?

Tags: vim

I tend to maximize a terminal to one screen, and vertically split several windows in Vim. Everything works fine for the first few windows on the left, but clicking past about the 220th column in the terminal doesn't work correctly. Any mouse clicks past column 220 seem to be wrapping around to column 1. I've tested in xterm, urxvt, and Gnome terminal with and without tmux/screen; always the same behavior. If I greatly increase the size of the font in Gnome terminal, I can click on the last column (although it is no longer past column #220).

If I run a command in a terminal that prints to standard output, I can click all the way to the right of the terminal. The problem does seem to be related to Vim.

I have `set mouse=a` in `.vimrc`. I'll post the entire file on request, but it doesn't seem to have anything else related to the mouse.

It's probably irrelevant, but I'm running Xmonad+Gnome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open up a terminal and maximize it. Run `vim`, and then enter `230ix` and hit escape. Your font should be small enough that the `x`'s do not wrap. Clicking on any but the last dozen or so 'x' characters will cause that character to be selected. Clicking on any of the last few 'x' characters, however, will cause the `x` in column 1 to be selected (for me, at least).

Comment: It is a very strange behavior.  I use urxvt and do not experience this problem at all, failing to reproduce it following your instructions.

Comment: Can't help, sorry, but I can confirm that I see the same behavior you describe with xterm, gnome-terminal, and rxvt. Looks like a bug to me?

Comment: Tried under Gnome, and a couple other window managers. Also, under gnome, I get an "Invalid register" error from vim when I click and drag (to select characters) past the 223rd column.

Comment: @redstreet: that's great, actually. At least there is good reason to believe that it is a bug.

For the record, I'm running Fedora 15, Vim 7.3 compiled Mar 17 2011 including patches 1-138. I couldn't find an existing bug report, so I'll file one.

Comment: I've heard about this behavior before, something about mouse handling in the tty in general.  Can you try opening another application that supports mouse interaction and see if it too has the same problem?

Comment: @Randy Morris: I'd tried it earlier on the output of `ls` and it worked fine. However, I tested it just now in `w3m`, and encountered the same problem. It seems that if it were an issue with the tty, that it would have occurred when using the mouse after running `ls` as well. Confirming the issue in `w3m` does raise the question, though. Thoughts?

Comment: I'll look around and see if I can find the thread I originally read about this in but my efforts so far to find it have been unsuccessful.

Comment: @Randy Morris found something: http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/4c137e64d2032441/b3993eaa89589619?lnk=gst&q=mouse#b3993eaa89589619

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This has been fixed in [Vim 7.3.632](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/7.3.632). See `:h sgr-mouse`. Or just put this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set ttymouse=sgr
```

If you want to be compatible with versions that don't have `mouse_sgr` compiled in, use:

```
if has("mouse_sgr")
    set ttymouse=sgr
else
    set ttymouse=xterm2
end
```

To see if your version of Vim has `mouse_sgr`, run `vim --version` from the command-line, or in Vim, enter `:version`, and look for `+mouse_sgr`.

If you're using older versions of screen, or terminal emulators that don't support SGR, you may need to upgrade or switch. These settings work with all new versions of screen, tmux, gnome-terminal, PuTTY/KiTTY, iTerm2, and Terminal.app, using `TERM=xterm-256color` or `screen-256color`.

**Update:** If you're using neovim, SGR support is enabled by default.

Comment: set ttymouse=sgr unfortunately doesn't work when using screen on OSX 10.10.3 with Vim 7.4

Comment: I haven't tried that. Could be a problem with the OSX termcap entry for screen, could be a problem with Terminal.app, could be a problem with OSX's screen build. OSX tools like screen are woefully out-of-date; you might have better luck with MacPorts (or Homebrew, if you must). It works fine with iTerm2 + MacPorts tmux + MacPorts vim; that's what I use daily. I highly recommend you ditch screen and switch to tmux anyway.

Comment: Spent a while wrestling with this, but there is an answer: the version of screen that comes with OSX is, as you say, woefully out of date. By using the most recent version, you can get actual 256 color support, but it does not have sgr mouse support. However, there is a patch which adds support that can be applied to the current head: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-devel/2014-04/msg00043.html  Applying that patch and rebuilding, as well as setting ttymouse=sgr inside of vim has it all working nicely now.

Comment: Screen is entirely obsoleted by tmux, IMHO. Also, the [screen source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/screen.c) is some of the scariest I've seen in a while.

Comment: I'm using terminal Vim 8.0.0851 with rxvt-unicode (urxvt) in Arch Linux.  When I set use "set ttymouse=sgr", Vim goes from ignoring the right side of the terminal to "clicking" stuff on the left of the console whenever I click on the right side.

Comment: It's almost certainly a problem with your terminal. It's probably moving the cursor to (column mod 255). Someone might have patched it. Try with xterm or a more modern terminal to confirm. Make sure your `TERM` is set correctly too.

Comment: @Synthead In your case use `set ttymouse=urxvt`, it's right there in `:h ttymouse`.

Comment: I don't know how many years of annoyance I could have avoided if I'd read this answer sooner...!

Answer (score 9):

**Edit**:
I deleted the bug report, as that tracker was for the website, not the text editor.

In looking in the *correct place* for an existing bug report, I found this:
http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/4c137e64d2032441/b3993eaa89589619?lnk=gst&q=mouse#b3993eaa89589619

To summarize, it was an xterm limitation that has been lifted. However, Vim does not yet support columns longer than 223.

---

**Original:**
This seems to be a bug, as supported by comments made by redstreet. I filed a bug report:

https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3389331&group_id=27891&atid=391887

Comment: Thank you for posting the bug report. This bug has been particularly annoying for me!

Comment: It's specifically a problem because I use the `tagbar` plugin, which opens up on the right-side of the window. I cannot click my mouse into it.

Comment: I use taglist, which I place on the left as a workaround. For tagbar, you can use `let g:tagbar_left = 1` in your vimrc.

Answer (score 4):

A few years later, the bug still seems to be present.
The solution I found is neovim: a modern refactor of vim. Among other features, this bug has been resolved.

I simply copied my .vimrc into .nvimrc, and my plugins just worked with nvim. Maybe I'll just keep using that.