# How to change tabs order in VIM?

Tags: vim, tabs, nerdtree

**Is there a way to change tabs order in `Vim`** (i.e. change the position of the tabs in the tab bar)? For example, let's say my current tabs are in this order:

```
A | B | C | D
```

But I would like to switch the position of the tabs to something like:

```
A | C | B | D
```

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a vim command to relocate a tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961581/is-there-a-vim-command-to-relocate-a-tab)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use `:tabmove` followed by the tab number to move past. For example, `:tabmove 3` will make the current tab move past the 3rd. `:tabmove 0` moves to the beginning and `:tabmove` (without a number) moves to the end.

Another way - though not orthodox - is to enable mouse via `:set mouse=a` and drag-and-drop tabs around. It might look simpler for a start.

Comment: I've gotten used to the (slightly) shorter version: `:tabm 3`

Comment: There's a way to use the mouse for this, I have updated the answer:)

Comment: If it's convenience you're looking for, you can take a look at my .vimrc file [here](https://github.com/kshenoy/dotvim/blob/master/mappings.vim), particularly lines #312-339. It is, in essence, the same as the previous answers, but with pretty wrapper around it.

Comment: kshenoy - The link is no longer valid as of 2013/11/29

Comment: Oddly, gVim won't let you move tabs around even with `:set mouse=a`. If you're using gVim and you're confused, the mouse trick only applies to the text menu displayed in "regular" vim.

Answer (score 11):

### Move Tabs to the Left / Right

To me it makes much more sense to move the tabs to the left or right of their current position instead of first figuring out the exact numerical position I want them at. These simple keymaps do exactly that:

```
noremap <A-Left>  :-tabmove<cr>
noremap <A-Right> :+tabmove<cr>
```

---

Now you'll be able to move the current tab:

- **To the left using:** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>
- **To the right using:** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>

For MacVim, try using `M` instead of `A` (i.e. `<M-Left>`)

Comment: This mapping does not move the tabs by one step on my Ubuntu 14.04 and vim 7.4.

Comment: I'm also on Ubuntu 14.04 with Vim 7.4 and it works for me. Maybe your terminal is not configured to handle `Alt` key. Try something else (such as your `Leader` key)

Comment: Sorry, I posted that previous comment a bit in a hurry. What I meant is, that mapping does not move tabs by one step, but moves them back and forth between two locations. Say `tab` is at location `A`; alt+right moves it to `B`, then alt+right does nothing but alt+left moves it back to `A`, then alt+left does nothing but alt+right moves it forth to `A`, and so on.

Comment: That's exactly the intention and answers the question. Try it with a few more tabs and you'll know why it's better.

Comment: Wow this is a much better technique. Just what I wanted.

Comment: Don't know why only +tabmove is working. (vim 7.4.629)

Answer (score 4):

For me -tabmove is not working.

I'm using below command: Ctrl+Shift+PageUp|PageDown.

```
nmap <C-S-PageUp>   :tabmove -1<cr>
nmap <C-S-PageDown> :tabmove +1<cr>
```

Comment: both -tabm and tabm-1 worked for me, gvim version 7.4 on linux