# Cannot resize pane with mouse

Tags: tabs, neovim

I use mouse often to resize panes. Recently I'm trying out tabs, and found that it's possible to switch tabs using mouse too, simply by clicking on a tab.

However, after successfully changing the tab by clicking on it using mouse, I am no longer able to resize the pane using mouse. Instead, **every time I click on the pane border and drag mouse cursor, the tabs get rearranged** (e.g. it looks like `:tabm` happens), as if the mouse click "stuck" the first time I clicked tab and now "holds" the tab.

**Is this a known problem, solvable by configuration?**. All I'm looking for is being able to resize panes even after I used mouse to select tabs.

**Edit**. My environment:

- macOS 0.12.2,
- neovim 0.2.0 (but the issue was with 0.1.7 as well).

Comment: What OS and version of vim are you using?

Comment: @JimU I've just updated the question

Comment: Have you tried using a minimal `init.vim` to verify it's not some other plugin(s) or setting(s) interfering with this?