# GNU screen mouse limitation

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal

My typical development environment is running a GNU screen session with vim in a full screen terminal (typically gnome-terminal).  The problem I've run into is that the mouse pointer is not interpreted correctly when clicking on a character in vim beyond around the 223rd character in the terminal.

I have tried the solution to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7000960/1364268) (adding `set ttymouse=sgr` to my `.vimrc`), and this solves the problem for running vim directly in the terminal but the limitation with the mouse still exists when using vim inside a screen session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching for GNU screen sgr support I came across a [patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-devel/2012-07/msg00004.html)! Here are the steps I used to apply the patch to screen on Ubuntu 14.04. (I've modified that patch to work with the source files downloaded from apt-get [here](https://gist.github.com/sbchisholm/ca120a366f0b1d3fc00b))

1. Pull down the screen source from apt-get:

   ```
   apt-get source screen
   ```
2. `cd` into the source directory and install the patch:

   ```
   patch -p1 < screen-sgr-patch.diff
   ```
3. Integrate local changes made by the patch:

   ```
   dpkg-source --commit
   ```
4. Build the new `.deb` files:

   ```
   dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
   ```

   (NOTE: it may complain about missing build dependencies but just install any of them 
          using `apt-get` and run `dpkg-buildpackage` again)
5. Install the patched screen package (you'll find this beside the source directory):

   ```
   dpkg -i screen_<version>_<arch>.deb
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure why this patch isn't pulled into screen, but I haven't had any issues using it so far.

Comment: Just so you know you can always flag a moderator to un community wiki your answer. (Although it might take a long time for them to change it)